# unable to get document.getElementByID("testclick").addEventListener to work

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I'm doing something phenomenally dumb here I'm sure of it; It's been several hours and I'm beginning to lose the will to live. What's worse is I've used this before successfully in a canvas but even that example isn't helping me.

html file (index.html)

```
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <div ID="testclick">
        <style>
            #testclick{
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:black;
            }
        </style>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript" src="test.js" ></script>
</body>
```

javascipt file (test.js)

```
(function(){
var el = document.getElementByID("testclick");
el.addEventListener("click", sockClicked, false);

function sockClicked(){
    console.log("HAR");
};
})();
```

Error Message: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I've googled and read several occurences of this error was combined with addEventListener.
Ive also read several tutorials on how to use getElementByID as well as addEventListener. But still no joy. Someone please save me from this endless turmoil. ;(

Answer (score 5):

It's [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), not `getElementByID`. Javascript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

your correct code for js function will be this:

```
(function(){
var el = document.getElementById("testclick");
el.addEventListener("click", sockClicked, false);

function sockClicked(){
    console.log("HAR");
};
})();
```